# Virtual PC on Windows 7 - Hardware-assisted virtualization is disabled

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am running a Lenovo Thinkpad T61 with an Intel Core 2 Duo T7300 processor.  When I run Virtual PC in Windows 7, I get the following error:

> Unable to start Windows Virtual PC because hardware-assisted virtualization is disabled.

When running the [Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ee2a17f-8538-4619-8d1c-05d27e11adb2&displaylang=en) from Microsoft says:

> Hardware-assited virtualization is not enabled on this computer.

Now, in the BIOS, I do have virtualization enabled and according to Intel [this processor](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=29760) supports Intel-VT.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Do a CPUID check and also update to the latest BIOS. Lenovo notebooks do sometimes come with VT-X disabled (not too sure why your BIOS says it's enabled, and it does not work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling Intel-VT requires a cold restart. Try going back into the BIOS, turn it off, and turn off the computer (don't just reboot). Then start up, go in the BIOS and enable it, then once again turn the PC **off**. Make sure you save your changes in the BIOS.

Boot up and start VPC, check the options and ensure it is enabled:

[image]

Comment: I don't recall if I powered off after enabling VT in the BIOS a few days ago.  I will give that a shot...

Comment: Well, that was the problem.  Powered off and back on, and now Virtual PC is working.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a second way to resolve this problem.  Microsoft released an update to Virtual PC which removes the requirement for hardware assisted virtualization.

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/03/18/windows-virtual-pc-no-hardware-virtualization-update-now-available-for-download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a stupid suggestion, but have you checked if there's a Bios update where this problem might be fixed?

Comment: It looks like I am on the latest revision from Lenovo.