# Why did Windows 7 XP Mode stopped working?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

Windows XP mode on Windows 7 works fine launching my legacy app, and then later on will not work with this error message:

> Unable to start Windows Virtual PC because hardware-assisted virtualization is disabled

[image]

If I disable virtualization in BIOS reboot, reenable, reboot, it seems to work again, but this keeps happening periodcially over and over. Any suggestions/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update your BIOS on your motherboard for starters.

Second, when you do see this occur you should run this tool:

http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

and see if Virtualization really turned off, or if there are program issues.

Comment: BIOS update was the answer. The virtualization setting would not stay between reboots, bios update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The following thread threats a similar problem:
[Virtual PC on Windows 7 - Hardware-assisted virtualization is disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/62006/virtual-pc-on-windows-7-hardware-assisted-virtualization-is-disabled):

> Enabling Intel-VT requires a cold
>   restart. Try going back into the BIOS,
>   turn VT off, and turn off the computer
>   (don't just reboot). Then start up, go
>   in the BIOS and enable VT, then once
>   again turn the PC off. Make sure you
>   save your changes in the BIOS.